# RDP over OpenVPN fails

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I have two routers at office. Let's say those R1 and R2.
The network looks like:

```
ISP - R1 - R2 - PC2
      |
      PC1


 R1 subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
 R1 WAN IP: using DDNS
 R1 LAN IP: 192.168.20.1
PC1 LAN IP: 192.168.20.100 (assigned by R1)

 R2 subnet: 129.168.10.0/24
 R2 WAN IP: 192.168.20.10 (assigned by R1)
 R2 LAN IP: 192.168.10.1
PC2 LAN IP: 192.168.10.100 (assigned by R2)
```

I made a port forwarding entry in R2 to connect PC2 using RDP: 12345 port to 192.168.10.100:3389

Now, I can make RDP connection from PC1 to PC2 through 192.168.20.10:12345.

This time, I created an OpenVPN settings in R1 router to connect PC2 at home.

```
OpenVPN subnet: 10.8.0.0/24 (the default one in R1)
```

I can connect OpenVPN successfully and get LAN IP for VPN, 10.8.0.6.
However, I cannot make RDP connection to PC2 through the port-forwarding address 192.168.20.10:12345.

By the way, I can make RPD connection from home using OpenVPN to PC1 without any port-forwarding settings in R1.

In short,

```
 PC1 to PC2: OK (using port forwarding in R2)
home to PC1: OK (using OpenVPN without any port forwarding)
home to PC2: fail (using OpenVPN + port forwarding in R2)
```

That is, home->PC1 and PC1->PC2 work but **home->PC2** does not work.

Windows shows the very general error message which does not help alot...

[image]

(This image is picked from internet)

I have absolutely no idea what to do now. What should I check?

Comment: Did you enable the group policies required to enable Remote Desktop on Windows?  Your issue isn't likely a port forwarding port.  You simply have not configured your system to be accessible remotely.  **It's basically the first reason listed.**

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't PC1 a remote one? I can connect from PC1 to PC2 already. Please read the 'In short' parts.

Comment: Could you maybe add the actual port forwarding rule and the routing tables of both routers to the question?

Comment: @xylosper - So you added the user to the appropriate group responsible for allowing remote access?

Comment: A VPN server on R1 does not automatically get you LAN access. You'll need to at least have the server configured to push a default or `192.168.20.0/24` route (or of course, you can have that in your client conf instead). The router will need to be allowed / configured to forward traffics between the VPN and the LAN. (There's a chance that the VPN clients are only allowed for WAN access.)